# Generateing all possible 16 digit number requireling less storage location

Tags: algorithm, perl

I am trying to generate all possible  16-digit decimal numbers.

I know that this will require a lot of storage, so I have tried to reduce the numbers by removing all  numbers that the 6th digit is not equal to the 3rd digit - 1. I have also made sure that no four consecutive digits are equal.

The problem comes when I am trying to remove all generated numbers which contain more than eight zeroes. For instance, I don't want to print the following `0000150000100210` or `0001000200343`.

Below is my Perl code for the above. I declare a global variable `$A` that is incremented each time any of the 16 digits is a zero, and then not to print the number when `$A` is more than eight. But it fails to work please help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$A=0;
for($a=0){
if($a==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($b=0;$b<6;$b++){
if($b==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($c=0;$c<6;$c++){
if($c==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($d=0;$d<6;$d++){
if($d==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($e=0;$e<6;$e++){
if($e==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($f=0;$f<6;$f++){
#check if all Numbers a-i are equal
#No 8 numbers can be the same in the same order
$Fc=$c-1;
if($Fc==-1){$Fc=5;}
#print "F==$Fc\n";
if($a==0&&$b==0&&$c==0&&$d==0&&$e==0&&$f==0||$a==0&&$b==0&&$c==0&&$d==0&&$e==0||$a==1&&$b==1&&$c==1&&$d==0&&$e==1&&f==1||$a==1&&$b==1&&$c==1&&$d==1&&$e==1||$a==2&&$b==2&&$c==2&&$d==2&&$e==2||$a==2&&$b==2&&$c==2&&$d==2&&$e==2
&&$f==2||$a==3&&$b==3&&$c==3&&$d==3&&$e==3||$a==3&&$b==3&&$c==3&&$d==3&&$e==3&&$f==3||$a==4&&$b==4&&$c==4&&$d==4&&$e==4||$a==4&&$b==4&&$c==4&&$d==4&&$e==4&&$f==4||$a==5&&$b==5&&$c==5&&$d==5&&$e==5||$a==5&&$b==5&&$c==5&&$d==5&&$e==5&&$f==5
){}
else{
if($f==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
#print "$a$b$c$d$e$Fc\n"
for($g=0;$g<6;$g++){
if($g==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($h=0;$h<6;$h++){
if($h==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
if($i==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($j=0;$j<6;$j++){
if($j==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($k=0;$k<6;$k++){
if($k==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($l=0;$l<6;$l++){
if($g==0&&$h==0&&$i==0&&$j==0&&$k==0&&$l==0||$g==0&&$h==0&&$i==0&&$j==0&&$k==0||$g==1&&$h==1&&$i==1&&$j==0&&$k==1&&$l==1||$g==1&&$h==1&&$i==1&&$j==1&&$k==1||$g==2&&$h==2&&$i==2&&$j==2&&$k==2
&&$l==2||$g==2&&$h==2&&$i==2&&$j==2&&$k==2||$g==3&&$h==3&&$i==3&&$j==3&&$k==3&&$l==3||$g==3&&$h==3&&$i==3&&$j==3&&$k==3||$g==4&&$h==4&&$i==4&&$j==4&&$k==4&&$l==4||$g==4&&$h==4&&$i==4&&$j==4&&$k==4||$g==5&&$h==5&&$i==5&&$j==5&&$k==5&&$l==5||$g==5&&$h==5&&$i==5&&$j==5&&$k==5
){}
else{
if($l==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($m=0;$m<6;$m++){
if($m==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($n=0;$n<6;$n++){
if($n==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($o=0;$o<6;$o++){
if($o==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
for($p=0;$p<6;$p++){
if($p==0){$A++;if($A>16){$A=0;}}
if($l==0&&$m==0&&$n==0&&$o==0&&$p==0||$l==0&&$m==0&&$n==0&&$o==0||$l==1&&$m==1&&$n==1&&$o==1&&$p==1||$l==1&&$m==1&&$n==1&&$o==1||$l==2&&$m==2&&$n==2&&$o==2&&$p==2||$l==2&&$m==2&&$n==2&&$o==2||$l==3&&$m==3&&$n==3&&$o==3&&$p==3||$l==3&&$m==3&&$n==3&&$o==3||$l==4&&$m==4&&$n==4&&$o==4&&$p==4||$l==4&&$m==4&&$n==4&&$o==4||$l==5&&$m==5&&$n==5&&$o==5&&$p==5||$l==5&&$m==5&&$n==5&&$o==5){}else{
#print "$A\n";
if($A>8){}
else{
print "$a$b$c$d$e$Fc$g$h$i$j$k$l$m$n$o$p\n"#Print The Generated  Numbers 
}

}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

#### Updated to reveal program structure

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$A = 0;

for ( $a = 0 ) {

    if ( $a == 0 ) {
        $A++;
        if ( $A > 16 ) {
            $A = 0;
        }
    }

    for ( $b = 0 ; $b < 6 ; $b++ ) {

        if ( $b == 0 ) {
            $A++;
            if ( $A > 16 ) {
                $A = 0;
            }
        }

        for ( $c = 0 ; $c < 6 ; $c++ ) {

            if ( $c == 0 ) {
                $A++;
                if ( $A > 16 ) {
                    $A = 0;
                }
            }

            for ( $d = 0 ; $d < 6 ; $d++ ) {

                if ( $d == 0 ) {
                    $A++;
                    if ( $A > 16 ) {
                        $A = 0;
                    }
                }

                for ( $e = 0 ; $e < 6 ; $e++ ) {

                    if ( $e == 0 ) {
                        $A++;
                        if ( $A > 16 ) {
                            $A = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    for ( $f = 0 ; $f < 6 ; $f++ ) {

                        #check if all Numbers a-i are equal
                        #No 8 numbers can be the same in the same order

                        $Fc = $c - 1;
                        if ( $Fc == -1 ) {
                            $Fc = 5;
                        }

                        #print "F==$Fc\n";

                        if ( $a == 0 && $b == 0 && $c == 0 && $d == 0 && $e == 0 && $f == 0
                                || $a == 0 && $b == 0 && $c == 0 && $d == 0 && $e == 0
                                || $a == 1 && $b == 1 && $c == 1 && $d == 0 && $e == 1 && f == 1
                                || $a == 1 && $b == 1 && $c == 1 && $d == 1 && $e == 1
                                || $a == 2 && $b == 2 && $c == 2 && $d == 2 && $e == 2
                                || $a == 2 && $b == 2 && $c == 2 && $d == 2 && $e == 2 && $f == 2
                                || $a == 3 && $b == 3 && $c == 3 && $d == 3 && $e == 3
                                || $a == 3 && $b == 3 && $c == 3 && $d == 3 && $e == 3 && $f == 3
                                || $a == 4 && $b == 4 && $c == 4 && $d == 4 && $e == 4
                                || $a == 4 && $b == 4 && $c == 4 && $d == 4 && $e == 4 && $f == 4
                                || $a == 5 && $b == 5 && $c == 5 && $d == 5 && $e == 5
                                || $a == 5 && $b == 5 && $c == 5 && $d == 5 && $e == 5 && $f == 5 ) {


                        }
                        else {

                            if ( $f == 0 ) {
                                $A++;
                                if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                    $A = 0;
                                }
                            }

                            #print "$a$b$c$d$e$Fc\n"

                            for ( $g = 0 ; $g < 6 ; $g++ ) {

                                if ( $g == 0 ) {
                                    $A++;
                                    if ( $A > 16 ) { $A = 0; }
                                }

                                for ( $h = 0 ; $h < 6 ; $h++ ) {

                                    if ( $h == 0 ) {
                                        $A++;
                                        if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                            $A = 0;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++ ) {

                                        if ( $i == 0 ) {
                                            $A++;
                                            if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                $A = 0;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        for ( $j = 0 ; $j < 6 ; $j++ ) {

                                            if ( $j == 0 ) {
                                                $A++;
                                                if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                    $A = 0;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            for ( $k = 0 ; $k < 6 ; $k++ ) {

                                                if ( $k == 0 ) {
                                                    $A++;
                                                    if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                        $A = 0;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                for ( $l = 0 ; $l < 6 ; $l++ ) {

                                                    if ( $g == 0 && $h == 0 && $i == 0 && $j == 0 && $k == 0 && $l == 0
                                                            || $g == 0 && $h == 0 && $i == 0 && $j == 0 && $k == 0
                                                            || $g == 1 && $h == 1 && $i == 1 && $j == 0 && $k == 1 && $l == 1
                                                            || $g == 1 && $h == 1 && $i == 1 && $j == 1 && $k == 1
                                                            || $g == 2 && $h == 2 && $i == 2 && $j == 2 && $k == 2 && $l == 2
                                                            || $g == 2 && $h == 2 && $i == 2 && $j == 2 && $k == 2
                                                            || $g == 3 && $h == 3 && $i == 3 && $j == 3 && $k == 3 && $l == 3
                                                            || $g == 3 && $h == 3 && $i == 3 && $j == 3 && $k == 3
                                                            || $g == 4 && $h == 4 && $i == 4 && $j == 4 && $k == 4 && $l == 4
                                                            || $g == 4 && $h == 4 && $i == 4 && $j == 4 && $k == 4
                                                            || $g == 5 && $h == 5 && $i == 5 && $j == 5 && $k == 5 && $l == 5
                                                            || $g == 5 && $h == 5 && $i == 5 && $j == 5 && $k == 5 ) {

                                                    }
                                                    else {

                                                        if ( $l == 0 ) {
                                                            $A++;
                                                            if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                                $A = 0;
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        for ( $m = 0 ; $m < 6 ; $m++ ) {

                                                            if ( $m == 0 ) {
                                                                $A++;
                                                                if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                                    $A = 0;
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            for ( $n = 0 ; $n < 6 ; $n++ ) {

                                                                if ( $n == 0 ) {
                                                                    $A++;
                                                                    if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                                        $A = 0;
                                                                    }
                                                                }

                                                                for ( $o = 0 ; $o < 6 ; $o++ ) {

                                                                    if ( $o == 0 ) {
                                                                        $A++;
                                                                        if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                                            $A = 0;
                                                                        }
                                                                    }

                                                                    for ( $p = 0 ; $p < 6 ; $p++ ) {

                                                                        if ( $p == 0 ) {
                                                                            $A++;
                                                                            if ( $A > 16 ) {
                                                                                $A = 0;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }

                                                                        if ( $l == 0 && $m == 0 && $n == 0 && $o == 0 && $p == 0
                                                                                || $l == 0 && $m == 0 && $n == 0 && $o == 0
                                                                                || $l == 1 && $m == 1 && $n == 1 && $o == 1 && $p == 1
                                                                                || $l == 1 && $m == 1 && $n == 1 && $o == 1
                                                                                || $l == 2 && $m == 2 && $n == 2 && $o == 2 && $p == 2
                                                                                || $l == 2 && $m == 2 && $n == 2 && $o == 2
                                                                                || $l == 3 && $m == 3 && $n == 3 && $o == 3 && $p == 3
                                                                                || $l == 3 && $m == 3 && $n == 3 && $o == 3
                                                                                || $l == 4 && $m == 4 && $n == 4 && $o == 4 && $p == 4
                                                                                || $l == 4 && $m == 4 && $n == 4 && $o == 4
                                                                                || $l == 5 && $m == 5 && $n == 5 && $o == 5 && $p == 5
                                                                                || $l == 5 && $m == 5 && $n == 5 && $o == 5 ) {

                                                                        }
                                                                        else {

                                                                            #print "$A\n";

                                                                            if ( $A > 8 ) {

                                                                            }
                                                                            else {
                                                                                print "$a$b$c$d$e$Fc$g$h$i$j$k$l$m$n$o$p\n"    #Print The Generated  Numbers
                                                                            }

                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very hard to understand. I see that you have tried explaining your problem but I believe you should try again. Do you or do you not want to print ALL 16-digit base-10 numbers? Why are you talking about storage? Are you going to store the numbers? Why? Why have you added those filters? There are so many unanswered questions here that I think you should try to rewrite the question to be more clear.

Comment: Show me storage filled with all 16-digit numbers in order, and I show you $10,000,000 worth of wasted storage. Have you tried to calculate how much will you save by your cost-cutting measures?

Comment: If you could print a million per second (which most screens will not be able to cope with), it would still take over 400 years for them all to scroll by. Same applies to any other processing you might want to do against the complete set. The schemes for reducing the count will not get close to giving a realistic target here. Could you give some context, because it does not seem worth trying to solve your generator issues from what is said so far

Comment: That is one crazy Perl program! *Please* tell me you didn't just keep adding closing braces at the end until it compiled?

Comment: `perl -e 'printf("%016d\n",$_) for 0..9999999999999999'` (this is still pretty dumb)

Comment: If you are trying to brute-force credit card numbers that might not be a very smart idea.

Comment: Yeah i want to store the numbers. I am preparing a proof of concept for a company  i work for that the algorithm they are using to generate the 16 digit code can be broken with little conditions (The conditions above ) eg. letting the 3rd number=x and the 6th number=y then (y=x-1) always. Also by only printing 0 for the first digit and eliminating all cases where the result has more than the same digit more than 8 times  i think will at least reduce the computation time.

Comment: @simbabque it's not trying to brute-force but its the company am working for that is trying to start creating  credits but i think their method is wrong so i want to show them that they should change

Comment: 142PB of storage though....

Comment: Just counting up to a billion takes about 20 seconds:
`time perl -E '1 for 1 .. 1e9'`

Comment: @EsirKings: I think your proof of concept has no basis in reality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then all that code is just to avoid printing numbers that have more than eight zeroes

You can do that like this

```
my $credit_card_number = "$a$b$c$d$e$Fc$g$h$i$j$k$l$m$n$o$p";
print $credit_card_number, "\n" unless $credit_card_number =~ tr/0// > 8;
```

But I still think your enterprise is a fruitless one